# How to preveny Android App from being saved by appsaver

Tags: android, security

As we all know that there are may options available to save the android app apk file.

so if the app is a paid app, it might become a risk for developer.

Could anyone here would be able to help me to know the best practice to be followed in order to prevent your android app from being copied by the app saver applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats where the Google Play Licencing service plays the role. Here is what is says " With Google Play Licensing, your application can query Google Play at run time to obtain the licensing status for the current user, then allow or disallow further use as appropriate." Check out this documentation for usage instruction [Here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html)